# using setBackgroundimageNamed displays wrong image

Tags: watchkit

I have an animated timer ring which uses numbered images `timer0.png` to `timer200.png` in an asset catalog. If I use `setBackgroundImageNamed("timer5")` on a group, it displays timer50. I'm assuming it looks for images with numbers after the name you specify and uses that instead, even if you are not animating. How can I force it to display timer5? Perhaps naming it 005 instead would work?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you do `setBackgroundImageNamed("timer5.jpg")` does that work?

Comment: When naming images timer005.png, it does not display the images when animating. I'm at a loss, looks like it could be a bug.

Comment: Hmm yea. I can replicate this. Let me try out a few things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue. Basically, when you ask for "timer5", WatchKit looks for the first frame of "timer5" which would be "timer50" (i.e. the 0th frame of the timer5 animation). To work around the issue, you can use `startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:duration:repeatCount:` with a range of length 1 so that your "animation" starts and ends at the requested frame number.

Comment: Yup. this seems to be the way